# Running Oozie using Cloudera VM issue

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am using cloudera quickstart in vmware to run sample Oozie.

I am trying to run some examples of Oozie that comes in Cloudera.

I am following this link: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/oozie/DG_Examples.html

I untared 'oozie-examples.tar.gz' and got examples directory.

When running the oozie, I get an error message:

```
[cloudera@localhost oozie-3.3.2+92]$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
```

o/p:

uce/job.properties -run
Error: E0901 : E0901: Namenode [localhost:8020] not allowed, not in Oozies whitelist

oozie-site.xml looks like:

vi /etc/oozie/conf.dist/oozie-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist</name>
    <value>
    localhost:8021
    </value>
    <description>
        Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist</name>
    <value>
    hdfs://localhost:8020
    </value>
    <description>
        Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
    </description>
</property>
```

vi job.properties look like:

```
hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have Cloudera running what does it say for the NameNode address when you click on the HDFS NameNode link in Firefox?

Comment: jobtracker: http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp and namenode: http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp

Comment: It should say something like this "NameNode '0.0.0.0:8020' (active)" the 0.0.0.0 IP is default config. In Cloudera Manager does it say the NameNode is up? If so please click on the HDFS NameNode link in FireFox and you should see the Cluster Summary in a simple text page, what does the first line on that page say in Bold Typeface?

Comment: NameNode '0.0.0.0:8020' (active)
Started: Sat Apr 05 19:00:54 PDT 2014
Version: 2.0.0-cdh4.4.0, c0eba6cd38c984557e96a16ccd7356b7de835e79
Compiled: Tue Sep 3 19:33:17 PDT 2013 by jenkins from Unknown
Upgrades: There are no upgrades in progress.
Cluster ID: cluster11
Block Pool ID: BP-780931682-127.0.0.1-1381159027878

Comment: How do I check if namenode is up? First line says :NameNode '0.0.0.0:8020' (active)

Comment: In a browser go to http://localhost:8042, does it come up. Also type hostname in at the command line and tell me what that says

Comment: localhost:8042: nothing comes up. [cloudera@localhost conf]$ hostname
localhost.localdomain

Comment: in your ozzie-site.xml file change the property values for the jobtracker and namenode to reflect the loaclhost.localdomain:port and not just localhost:port as it is now. Then also try http://localhost.localdomain:8042

Comment: do I need to make changes in job.properties?

Comment: Not sure, you should correct the ozzie-site.xml and retry your job submission to see if your hostname / whitelist work

Comment: <property>
        <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist</name>
        <value>localhost.localdomain:8021</value>
        <description>
            Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
        </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist</name>
        <value>localhost.localdomain:8020</value>
        <description>
            Whitelisted job tracker for Oozie service.
        </description>
    </property>

Comment: job.properties is:nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

Comment: I saw that above, the problem with this VM is that there are some config options referencing localhost and some reference localhost.localdomain. Not your fault as it came that way, but it means you have to tweak it as you learn.

Comment: Still getting same message    [cloudera@localhost oozie-3.3.2+92]$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: E0901 : E0901: Namenode [localhost:8020] not allowed, not in Oozies whitelist

Comment: go ahead and change that first line in job.properties to reference the localhost.localdomain:8020

Comment: [cloudera@localhost oozie-3.3.2+92]$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: HTTP error code: 500 : Internal Server Error

Comment: job.properties: 
nameNode=localhost.localdomain:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce

Comment: In job.properties file, I replaced localhost with:  localhost.localdomain. And it fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In job.properties file, I replaced localhost with: localhost.localdomain. And it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like following your /etc/hosts.

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

Visit this link for details.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1516

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment posted as an answer.

Comment: suggested method is worth a try at least.

Comment: You will get voted down whether its a question or an answer if it is poorly phrased and not well written. If you know the answer post as such. If you answer incorrectly that is also a vote down situation. If you reference an Issue log as an answer say so by explaining within your answer. This answer will be come up each time someone asks a similar question, if it is correct and well written it will help many people for a long time. I see you corrected and edited your answer, If it is the correct answer you might add more detail.

Comment: Valid comments. Will help me improve the responses.

Comment: [cloudera@localhost etc]$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
It is what I have